JUnit test suite @IncludeTags is also running JUnit4 tests without @Tags
I want my test suite to only run the @Tagged tests and ignore the ones annotated with @RunWith.
I have JUnit 4 and 5 tests. I have a test suite that uses @IncludeTags("myTag"). I have JUnit5 tests that are annotated with @Tag("myTag"). But the package also contains tests that are annotated with @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class).
This is what my test suite class looks like:
@Suite
@SelectPackages("my.package")
@IncludeTags("myTag")
public class myTestSuite {
}


The suite requires a test engine and the exclusion of the other engines to prevent test duplication. Without seeing your pom or Gradle file diagnostics are not possible.

Thanks, will talk to infrastructure folks.
